# What is the largest $n\times n$ square lattice that can be $k$-colored such that no rectangles with same-colored vertices exist?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

It is fairly well known that for any $k$-coloring of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, it is impossible to color the vertices such that you never get a rectangle with axes parallel to the x and y-axis with vertices of the same color. In fact, it is known that you cannot color an $(k+1) \times (\frac{k^2(k+1)}{2}+1)$ lattice of points that meets this criterion. For example, you cannot 2-color the $3\times 7$ lattice in this manner. You *can*, however, color the $(k+1) \times (\frac{k^2(k+1)}{2})$ lattice in this way. One such successful 2-coloring of the $3\times 6$ lattice is below.

[image: ![enter image description here]

So, if the $3\times 6$ lattice is 2-colorable in this fashion, it is a natural question to ask, "what about the $6\times 6$ lattice?". As it turns out, the answer to this is "no". We can prove this by first showing you cannot 2-color the $5\times 6$ lattice.

After some experimentation, one sees that the only successful 2-coloring of the $4\times 6$ lattice is some permutation of the rows and columns of the below.

[image]

If one adds a column to the right, it becomes apparent that the top-right vertex can neither be red nor blue: in the case of the former, we eventually see that the fourth-row vertex cannot be red or blue, and in the case of the latter, we see the same for the third-row vertex. Therefore, the $6\times 6$ lattice cannot be colored like this - QED.

However, what about the $5\times 5$ lattice? It becomes clear that we essentially have six unique ways to color in the first three rows, seen below (again, barring permutations of the rows and columns). I know that out of these six, you cannot 2-color the top-left one successfully. I have yet to try the others, but would not be surprised to find you cannot achieve this for any configuration.

[image]

For what it is worth, it can be shown that yes, the $4\times 4$ lattice can be successfully colored like this, which will be shown at the end. However, this is only for 2-coloring. What about 3-coloring, or 4-coloring? What about $n$-coloring in general? If I had to make a conjecture, the most I would be willing to say is that you can *never* make a $(\frac{k^2(k+1)}{2})\times (\frac{k^2(k+1)}{2})$ lattice that can be colored like this, but even for that I don't know where to start proving it, and I don't know how to move that upper bound any lower. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generalization of the $(k+1) \times (\frac{k^2(k+1)}{2}+1)$ proof to square grids.

Suppose we have an $n \times n$ grid. If a column of the grid has $n_i$ squares of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color, with $n_1 + \dots + n_k = n$, then it has $\binom{n_1}{2} + \dots + \binom{n_k}{2}$ monochromatic pairs of squares, which can never repeat in the same color in a different column. By convexity, this number is at least $k\binom{n/k}{2}$.

The total supply of such pairs is $k \binom n2$: there are $\binom n2$ pairs of squares, and each pair can be monochromatic in $k$ different colors. So the constraint on $n$ is that $nk \binom{n/k}{2} \le k \binom n2$: we can pick $n$ columns without exhausting the supply. This inequality just barely fails for $n = k^2+k$: we get $\frac12 k^2(k+1)(k^2+k)$ on the left and $\frac12 k^2(k+1)(k^2+k-1)$ on the right.

Therefore a $(k^2+k) \times (k^2+k)$ lattice can never be colored, but there is still hope for a $(k^2+k-1) \times (k^2+k-1)$ lattice.

We can destroy this hope and reduce the bound by $1$, incidentally proving that when $k=2$, $4\times 4$ is best possible.

In this $(k^2+k-1) \times (k^2+k-1)$ lattice, the most even way to color a column is to use one color $k$ times and the others $k+1$ times, which uses up $\binom k2 + (k-1)\binom{k+1}{2} = \frac12 k(k^2+k-2)$ monochromatic pairs. We have a total supply of $k \binom{k^2+k-1}{2}$ monochromatic pairs; dividing by $k^2+k-1$, that gives us $\frac 12k(k^2+k-2)$ per column. So the only way we have any chance is to color each column in the most even way possible.

In every column, one color is underused. With $k^2+k-1$ columns, not every color can be underused $k+1$ times; one color is only underused $k$ times. Across all $k^2+k-1$ columns, that color appears in $k\binom k2 + (k^2-1)\binom{k+1}{2} = $ monochromatic pairs, which is more than the $\binom{k^2+k-1}{2}$ monochromatic pairs of that color we are allowed. Some monochromatic pair repeats in that column, giving us a rectangle.

Now we have an upper bound of $(k^2+k-2) \times (k^2+k-2)$, which is possible for $k=2$.

I don't know if this upper bound is tight, but it is the right order of magnitude: at least for all prime powers $k$, we can $k$-color the $k^2 \times (k^2+k)$ lattice. Here is an example when $k=3$:

[image]

The idea is to find $k+1$ partitions of ${1,\dots,k^2}$ so that no two elements are in the same partition together. To use a partition to color a column, assign color to each part of the partition, and use that color on every element of that part. Each partition can be used on $k$ columns if we permute the colors assigned to the parts. in the grid above, the first $3$ columns use the partition $\{1,2,3\} \cup \{4,5,6\} \cup \{7,8,9\}$. The next $3$ use the partition $\{1,5,9\} \cup \{2,6,7\} \cup \{3,4,8\}$.

How do we find these $k+1$ partitions? We identify $\{1,\dots,k^2\}$ with $\mathbb F_k^2$, where $\mathbb F_k$ is the field with $k$ elements. The plane $\mathbb F_k^2$ can be partitioned into the set of all lines with a given slope. The slope  of a line can be an element of $\mathbb F_k$, or $\infty$ for vertical lines: $k+1$ possibilities. Any two points are in only one line, so they are together in only one partition.

In particular, the $k^2 \times k^2$ square lattice can also be $k$-colored when $k$ is a prime power. So the optimal value is somewhere between $k^2$ and $k^2+k-2$.